# Graph of the function $\frac{\sin 5\theta}{\sin^5 \theta}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I was trying to  visualize a the graph of the function $\frac{\sin 5\theta}{\sin^5 \theta}$. After considering where the function is increasing and where it is decreasing  , I can get the idea of it's graph. Can anyone please check it if it is correct or not.[image]

Comment: Desmos agrees!!

Comment: You can use desmos to graph functions. Your function - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vqpktdey5g

Answer (score 2):

I will provide a method  to graph this function over $[0,2\pi]$. The passages you have to follow are:

1. Let $f(\theta)=\frac{\sin(5\theta)}{\sin^5(\theta)}$.
2. Calculate the domain of $f(\theta)$. So, you have to impose $\sin^5(\theta)\neq0\leftrightarrow\theta\neq0 + k\pi, k\in Z$. These are the asymptotes.
3. Compute the $\Im(f(\theta))$. This is very simple: $\Im(f(\theta))=[-4,+\infty]$.
4. Calculate the intersections with $x=0$. In this case $f(0)$ is not defined.
5. Compute the intersections with $y=0$. You have $f(\theta)=0\leftrightarrow\theta=\frac{k}{5}\pi,k\in Z$.
6. Calculate when $f'(\theta)=0$ where $f'(\theta)$ is the derivate of $f(\theta)$. You have that: $$f'(\theta)=5\csc^5(\theta)(\cos(5\theta)-\sin(5\theta)\cot(\theta))=0$$ 
   The solutions are: $$\theta_1=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi\: \vee \:\theta_2=\frac{3\pi}{4}+k\pi\: \vee \: \theta_3=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi,k \in Z.$$
   At $\theta_1=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi$ and at $\theta_2=\frac{3\pi}{4}+k\pi$ you have a minimum.

   At $\theta_3=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ a relative maximum. Also: $f(\theta_1)=f(\theta_2)=-4$ and $f(\theta_3)=1$.
7. When $\theta$ approaches $0,\pi$ from both sides you have $f(\theta)\rightarrow+\infty   $.
8. Graph the function $f(\theta)$ in $[0,2\pi]$:

[image]

The two plots are exactly the same.

Comment: could you please explain/give a link for step 3? I'm not exactly familiar with that concept

Comment: @sai-kartik: $\Im(f(\theta))$ is simply the image or the codomain of the function $f$. In this case $\Im(f(\theta))=[-4,+\infty]$ because there are no values of $\theta$ for which $f(\theta)<-4$.

Comment: thanks![ also there's a missing bracket on step 6 :)  ]

Comment: @sai-kartik: yes, corrected. I hope it has been useful for you.

Comment: it has! thanks again

Comment: @sai-kartik: maybe a $+1$?